# Can't create windows 10 powershell shortcut with admin privilege

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

I want to create shortcut to powershell with admin privileges, but *start as administrator* option is disabled and i am using admin account on Windows 10. 
I can start admin powershell via context menu, but i wan't to create keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had to create either an additional .cmd or .bat file that then calls the powershell script.  Shortcuts to those files allow you to check the "Run as Administrator" option.

```
@echo off
powershell.exe -Command "C:\Foo.ps1"
```

Comment: But i don't have "Run As Admin" option for that bat file.